# Swift: Appending array makes subview disappear

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to display a series of subclassed UIButtons programmatically (Swift) while also adding them to an array to be used elsewhere. In `viewWillAppear` of my View Controller, I have the following code:

```
for index in 1...3 {
    let btn = CustomBtn()
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100+(CGFloat(index)*50), 100, 100)
    btn.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    btn.setTitle("\(index)", forState: .Normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

    self.view.addSubview(btn)
    btnArray.append(btn)
}
```

When I run the app, the buttons don't appear on my screen, although printing `btnArray.count` yields 3 as expected. Adding subviews via iterating through the array doesn't work, either. When I delete `btnArray.append(btn)`, however, the buttons appear just fine.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

P.S. My endgame goal is to add all the buttons in `btnArray` to a stack view in a UICollectionViewCell, if that makes a difference. For likely the same reason as above, the stack view won't show up on my screen, either.

Comment: I would suggest to try this in `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews` and add condition (`var didLayoutSubview`), cause that function can be called multiple times and to add only once

Comment: I agree with @JuicyFruit, viewDidLoad is too soon if you are coding in terms of frame, use viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews instead for that. **BEWARE** - for frames only! You can add them as subviews in viewDidLoad. **ALSO** - be aware that arrays in iOS (and most languages and platforms are zero-based. In Swift if you wish to loop through an array, the best syntax is **for index in 0..<array.count**.